# Flutter auto_route, getter 'key' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:myapp/core/routes/router.gr.dart' as app_router;

child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'MyApp',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<app_router.Router>(
      router: app_router.Router()
    ),
```

I have implememented autoroute however I get an error here that the getter key was called on null

Answer (score 5):

As Masnun pointed out, commenting out the line 37 solves the issue. However, there is a different solution that doesn't involve touching the source of the auto_route.

I fixed this issue by removing `.builder` from:

```
builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(
  router: Router(),
  ...
),
```

and changed to

```
builder: ExtendedNavigator(
  router: Router(),
  ...
),
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here is [this](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/blob/master/auto_route/lib/src/extended_navigator.dart#L37) line (line 37).

```
key: GlobalObjectKey(nav.key),
```

Commenting out the line from library works fine for me. It may be a temporary problem.

Comment: Discussion at GitHub: https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/257